# Check if the parameter passed in the URL is a directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I've used this same friendly URL logic and it worked perfectly, I'm having trouble checking the directory, instead of displaying the message, it's redirecting to the directory typed in the URL.

*URLDynamic.class.php*

```
class URLDynamic
{
    private $ArrayParam;
    public  $param;
    public  $sepURL;

    public function ArrayParam()
    {
        if ( isset ( $_GET['url'] ) ) :
            $this->param  = addslashes ( rtrim ( $_GET['url'] ) );
            $this->sepURL = array_filter ( explode ( "/", $this->param ) );
        endif;

    }

    private function PushParam()
    {
        $this->ArrayParam = $this->ArrayParam();

        if ( isset ( $_GET['s'] ) ) :

            $Search = new Search;
            $Search->GetSearch();

        elseif ( isset ( $this->sepURL[0] ) ) :

            if ( is_dir ( $this->sepURL[0] ) ) :
                echo "Error 404";
            else :
            endif;  

        else :

            $Home = new Home;
            $Home->GetHome();

        endif;

    }

    public function GetURL()
    {
        return $this->PushParam();
    }
}
```

*.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: If the URL is an existing directory inside of your public webroot, it will never execute the PHP code due to the htaccess line `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d`.  You would need to call index.php directly with the desired url parameter to check.  If you do not need to provide a dir listing and you use the index.php file as your entry point, you can probably safely remove that line.  You should probably also read the PSR-1, PSR-2 and PSR-12 standards at https://www.php-fig.org/